# Скорость загрузки страницы Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Подскажите как получить или просчитать время загрузки страницы в `Selenium Java`. Любой драйвер.

Суть вообще в том что на странице имеется скрипт js. Мне нужно узнать время загрузки страницы с этим скриптом и без него.

Спасибо.

Comment: встроенный профилировщик IDE пробовали??

Comment: @Ep1demic в первые о таком слышу - нет, не пробовал. можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: какой IDE ("улучшенный" редактор кода) пользуетесь?

Comment: @Ep1demic а. IDEA

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать стандартные методы IDE. Запоминаешь время начала выполнения кода (при создании драйвера) и точку окончания (после удаления драйвера). Зная это сможешь узнать кол-во сек затраченное на прохождение теста.

Comment: неверно. можно создать драйвер сегодня, а завтра только открыть сайт, а послезавтра завершить драйвер. это не означает, что сайт грузился 3 дня